# Using my constructor of an object that contains another class as an attribute

Tags: java

I'm trying to test my class `Location` that uses two other classes as attributes `Address` and `Geolocation` However when constructing the object from main I get a pointer error.

This is what I have in main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class LocationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Location> locationList = new ArrayList<>();
        locationList.add(new Location(new Address(1, "Abubakr rd Almorsalat", "Riyadh", "Saudi Arabia"), new Geolocation(24.7136, 46.6753, 612), 1, "Prince Sultan University"));
        locationList.add(new Location(new Address(1, "Nassria st", "Sfax", "Tunisia"), new Geolocation(34.7478, 10.7662, 20), 2, "Second Location"));
        locationList.get(1).getGeolocation().setAltitude(20);
        locationList.get(0).getAddress().setStreetNumber(15);
        for(Location i : locationList) {
            System.out.println(i.getGeolocation());
        }

    }
}
```

and I have getters and setters for the two classes I'm using inside of `Location` this is their set method

```
public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address.setStreetNumber(address.getStreetNumber());
    this.address.setStreetName(address.getStreetName());
    this.address.setCity(address.getCity());
    this.address.setCountry(address.getCountry());
}

public void setGeolocation(Geolocation geolocation) {
    this.geolocation.setLatitude(geolocation.getLatitude());
    this.geolocation.setLongitude(geolocation.getLongitude());
    this.geolocation.setAltitude(geolocation.getAltitude());
}
```

I have a feeling that the problem is here, I'm not sure

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at quiz01.fall2016.Location.setAddress(Location.java:59)
at quiz01.fall2016.Location.<init>(Location.java:20)
at quiz01.fall2016.LocationTest.main(LocationTest.java:13)
```

The constructor

```
public Location(Address address, Geolocation geolocation, int id, String name) {
    setAddress(address);
    setGeolocation(geolocation);
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
}
```

Comment: could you also post your error?

Comment: post the constructor of `Location`

Comment: I edited the post so it has both the error and the constructor

Answer (score 2):

Before `setAddress` calls setters on `this.address`, make sure you are initializing `this.address`.

By default, all the objects will be initialized with `null`, so you are hitting NullPointerException.

Your constructor should be as follows

```
public Location(Address address, Geolocation geolocation, int id, String name) {
    // Initialize objects.
    this.address = new Address();
    this.geolocation = new Geolocation();
    setAddress(address);
    setGeolocation(geolocation);
    setId(id);
    setName(name);
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you very much.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I have specified right? 
By default, all the objects will be initialized with null, so you are hitting NullPointerException.

Comment: @user3261806 Please accept the answer if it has resolved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should create `Location` class as follows:

```
public class Location {

    private Address address;
    private Geolocation geolocation;
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Location() {
        super();
    }

    public Location(Address address, Geolocation geolocation, int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.address = address;
        this.geolocation = geolocation;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // ... other methods ...
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you are assuming that `this.address` is initialized automatically, whereas, it is not. You haven't intiailized it, that's the reason you are facing `NullPointerException`.

Change you method `setAddress` like this :

```
public void setAddress(Address address) {

    this.address = new Addess();

    this.address.setStreetNumber(address.getStreetNumber());
    this.address.setStreetName(address.getStreetName());
    this.address.setCity(address.getCity());
    this.address.setCountry(address.getCountry());

}
```

You will have to make similar change for GeoLocation as well.